# Grid control for ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to move a project from web forms to MVC. The question is: is there a control, plug-in, helper, etc. to create a grid (better if is using AJAX) in MCV at the same way that in web forms?

And the same about Control Toolkit for web forms, is there any equivalent project for MVC? I've been struggling for a while with jMvc Codeplex but it looks it's only for VS2008, not VS2010.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is [MvcContrib](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) which comes with the [MvcContrib grid](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation).

There are a lot of tutorials for it, such as [this](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2009/03/28/walkthrough-full-example-of-using-mvccontrib-grid-with-jquery-datatable.aspx), however most seem pretty old, such as they don't use the new razor syntax yet. But the concept is pretty much the same.

Probably if you just use `@` instead of `<% %>` most tutorials will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik also offers a free grid for open source projects. It is pretty powerful and the API is clean.

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx